# How to write Extended Euclidean Algorithm code wise in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question which is actually requires a bit of understanding Euclidian Algorithm. Problem is simple. An int "First" and int "Second" numbers are given by the user via Scanner.
Than we need to find greatest common divisor of them. Than the process goes like explained below:

Now Assume that the First number is: 42 and the Second is: 30 - they've given by the user. -

int x, y;

(x * First) + (y * Second) = gcd(First, Second); // x ? y ?

To Find GCD you may use: gcd(First, Second); Code is below:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b)    
    {    
        if(a == 0 || b == 0) return a+b; // base case   
        return gcd(b,a%b);    
    }
```

Sample Input: First: 24 Second: 48 and Output should be x: (-3) and y: 2
Sample Input: First: 42 Second: 30 and Output should be x: (-2) and y: 3
Sample Input: First: 35 Second: 05 and Output should be x: (0) and y: 1

```
 (x * First) + (y * Second) = gcd(First, Second); // How can we find x and y ?
```

I would very appreciate it if you could show a solution code wise in java thanks for checking!

Comment: You seem to understand the problem and how to solve it... What stops you from writing a solution ( or at least attempting ) ?

Comment: Google for "Bezout's Theorem" which will calculate _x_ and _y_.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Bezout's Theorem helped a lot I'll share the solution as soon as possible, thanks again.

Comment: This looks like _Extended_ Euclidean Algorithm.  There's an entry for this in Wikipedia that refers to Bezout's identity.

Comment: Googled and I found exactly what you said. It leads to Extended Euclidean Algorithm but it seems hard to implement it into java with code wise.

Comment: It's actually not that hard, once you understand what the article is telling you to do.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's for helping me out ajb I solved it after digging your answer. So for the people who would like to see code wise:

```
public class Main    
{    
public static void main (String args[])   
{   
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")    
    System.out.println("How many times you would like to try ?")
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int len = read.nextInt();    

    for(int w = 0; w < len; w++)    
    {
        System.out.print("Please give the numbers seperated by space: ")
        read.nextLine();
        long tmp = read.nextLong();
        long m = read.nextLong();
        long n;
        if (m < tmp) {      
            n = m;
            m = tmp;
        }
        else {
            n = tmp;
        }

        long[] l1 = {m, 1, 0};
        long[] l2 = {n, 0, 1};
        long[] l3 = new long[3]; 

        while (l1[0]-l2[0]*(l1[0]/l2[0]) > 0) {
            for (int j=0;j<3;j++) l3[j] = l2[j]; 
            long q = l1[0]/l2[0];        
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            l2[i] = (l1[i]-l2[i]*q);
            }

            for (int k=0;k<3;k++) l1[k] = l3[k];
        }

        System.out.printf("%d %d %d",l2[1],l2[2],l2[0]); // first two Bezouts identity Last One gcd
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Extended Euclidean Algorithm is described in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).  The basic algorithm is stated like this (it looks better in the Wikipedia article):

> More precisely, the standard Euclidean algorithm with a and b as
>   input, consists of computing a sequence q<sub>1</sub>,...,
>   q<sub>k</sub> of quotients and a sequence r<sub>0</sub>,...,
>   r<sub>k+1</sub> of remainders such that
>
> r<sub>0</sub>=a
>  r<sub>1</sub>=b
>  ...
>   r<sub>i+1</sub>=r<sub>i-1</sub>-q<sub>i</sub> r<sub>i</sub> and 0 <
>   r<sub>i+1</sub> < |r<sub>i</sub>|
>  ...
>
> It is the main property of Euclidean division that the inequalities on
>   the right define uniquely r<sub>i+1</sub> from r<sub>i-1</sub> and
>   r<sub>i</sub>.
>
> The computation stops when one reaches a remainder r<sub>k+1</sub>
>   which is zero; the greatest common divisor is then the last non zero
>   remainder r<sub>k</sub>.
>
> The extended Euclidean algorithm proceeds similarly, but adds two
>   other sequences defined by
>
> s<sub>0</sub>=1, s<sub>1</sub>=0
>  t<sub>0</sub>=0,
>   t<sub>1</sub>=1
>  ...
>   s<sub>i+1</sub>=s<sub>i-1</sub>-q<sub>i</sub> s<sub>i</sub>
>   t<sub>i+1</sub>=t<sub>i-1</sub>-q<sub>i</sub> t<sub>i</sub>

This should be easy to implement in Java, but the mathematical way it's expressed may make it hard to understand.  I'll try to break it down.

Note that this is probably going to be easier to implement in a loop than recursively.

In the standard Euclidean algorithm, you compute r<sub>i+1</sub> in terms of r<sub>i-1</sub> and r<sub>i</sub>.  This means that you have to save the two previous versions of *r*.  This part of the formula:

> r<sub>i+1</sub>=r<sub>i-1</sub>-q<sub>i</sub> r<sub>i</sub> and 0 <
>   r<sub>i+1</sub> < |r<sub>i</sub>|
>  ...

just means that r<sub>i+1</sub> will be the remainder when r<sub>i-1</sub> is divided by r<sub>i</sub>.  q<sub>i</sub> is the quotient, which you don't use in the standard Euclidean algorithm, but you do use in the extended one.  So Java code to perform the standard Euclidean algorithm (i.e. compute the GCD) might look like:

```
prevPrevR = a;
prevR = b;
while ([something]) {
    nextR = prevPrevR % prevR;
    quotient = prevPrevR / prevR;  // not used in the standard algorithm
    prevPrevR = prevR;
    prevR = nextR;
}
```

Thus, at any point, `prevPrevR` will be essentially r<sub>i-1</sub>, and `prevR` will be r<sub>i</sub>.  The algorithm computes the next *r*, r<sub>i+1</sub>, then shifts everything which in essence increments *i* by 1.

The extended Euclidean algorithm will be done the same way, saving two *s* values `prevPrevS` and `prevS`, and two *t* values `prevPrevT` and `prevT`.  I'll let you work out the details.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code that I came up with if anyone is still looking. It is in C# but I am sure it similar to java. Enjoy

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<long> U = new List<long>();
        List<long> V = new List<long>();
        List<long> W = new List<long>();

        long a, b, d, x, y;

        Console.Write("Enter value for a: ");
        string firstInput = Console.ReadLine();
        long.TryParse(firstInput, out a);

        Console.Write("Enter value for b: ");
        string secondInput = Console.ReadLine();
        long.TryParse(secondInput, out b);

        long temp;
        //Make sure that a > b
        if(a < b)
        {
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
        }
        //Initialise List U
        U.Add(a);
        U.Add(1);
        U.Add(0);

        //Initialise List V
        V.Add(b);
        V.Add(0);
        V.Add(1);

       while(V[0] > 0)
        {
            decimal difference = U[0] / V[0];
            var roundedDown = Math.Floor(difference);
            long rounded = Convert.ToInt64(roundedDown);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                W.Add(U[i] - rounded * V[i]);

            U.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                U.Add(V[i]);

            V.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                V.Add(W[i]);

            W.Clear();

        }

       d = U[0];
       x = U[1];
       y = U[2];
       Console.WriteLine("\nd = {0}, x = {1}, y = {2}", d, x, y);

        //Check Equation
        Console.WriteLine("\nEquation check: d = ax + by\n");
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} = {1}({2}) + {3}({4})", d, a, x, b, y);
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} = {1} + {2}", d, a*x, b*y);
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0} = {1}", d, (a * x) + (b * y));
        if (d == (a * x) + (b * y))
            Console.WriteLine("\t***Equation is satisfied!***");   
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\tEquation is NOT satisfied!");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should try to post answers that are in the correct language... Similar to Java is not Java. Be cautious posting these kinds of answers, they may be removed as off-topic or not relevant.