# Implementing Euclid's Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, return, greatest-common-divisor

I've been trying to implement Euclid's algorithm in Java for 2 numbers or more.The problem with my code is that

a) It works fine for 2 numbers,but returns the correct value multiple times when more than 2 numbers are entered.My guess is that this is probably because of the return statements in my code.

b) I don't quite understand how it works.Though I coded it myself,I don't quite understand how the return statements are working.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GCDCalc {

static int big, small, remainder, gcd;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Remove duplicates from the arraylist containing the user input.

    ArrayList<Integer> listofnum = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("GCD Calculator");
    System.out.println("Enter the number of values you want to calculate the GCD of: ");
    int counter = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
        int val = sc.nextInt();
        listofnum.add(val);
    }

    // Sorting algorithm.
    // This removed the need of conditional statements(we don't have to
    // check if the 1st number is greater than the 2nd element
    // before applying Euclid's algorithm.
    // The outer loop ensures that the maximum number of swaps are occurred.
    // It ensures the implementation of the swapping process as many times
    // as there are numbers in the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < listofnum.size(); i++) {
        // The inner loop performs the swapping.
        for (int j = 1; j < listofnum.size(); j++) {
            if (listofnum.get(j - 1) > listofnum.get(j)) {
                int dummyvar = listofnum.get(j);
                int dummyvar2 = listofnum.get(j - 1);
                listofnum.set(j - 1, dummyvar);
                listofnum.set(j, dummyvar2);

            }
        }
    }

    // nodup contains the array containing the userinput,without any
    // duplicates.
    ArrayList<Integer> nodup = new ArrayList();
    // Remove duplicates.
    for (int i = 0; i < listofnum.size(); i++) {
        if (!nodup.contains(listofnum.get(i))) {
            nodup.add(listofnum.get(i));
        }
    }

    // Since the array is sorted in ascending order,we can easily determine
    // which of the indexes has the bigger and smaller values.
    small = nodup.get(0);
    big = nodup.get(1);
    remainder = big % small;

    if (nodup.size() == 2) {
        recursion(big, small, remainder);
    } else if (nodup.size() > 2) {
        largerlist(nodup, big, small, 2);
    } else // In the case,the array only consists of one value.
    {
        System.out.println("GCD: " + nodup.get(0));
    }
}

// recursive method.
public static int recursion(int big, int small, int remainder) {
    remainder = big % small;
    if (remainder == 0) {
        System.out.println(small);
    } else {
        int dummyvar = remainder;
        big = small;
        small = dummyvar;
        recursion(big, small, remainder);
    }
    return small;
}

// Method to deal with more than 2 numbers.
public static void largerlist(ArrayList<Integer> list, int big, int small, int counter) {
    remainder = big % small;
    gcd = recursion(big, small, remainder);

    if (counter == list.size()) {

    } else if (counter != list.size()) {
        big = gcd;
        small = list.get(counter);
        counter++;
        largerlist(list, gcd, small, counter);
    }

  }
}
```

I apologize in advance for any formatting errors etc.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: See this answer [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004830/how-to-write-extended-euclidean-algorithm-code-wise-in-java)

Comment: Not sure about the rest of it. But if you want to sort and remove dups, I would just throw the numbers into a TreeSet. Eliminate that cruft, at least.

Comment: FYI, here's a [1-line Java implementation if euclid's algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6619618/256196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these two assignments are the wrong way around

```
    big = gcd;
    small = list.get(counter);
```

and then `big` not used

```
    largerlist(list, gcd, small, counter);
```

Also you've used static variables, which is usually a problem.

I suggest removing static/global variables and generally don't reuse variables.

Edit: Oh yes, `return`. You've ignored the return value of the `recursion` method when called from the `recursion` method. That shouldn't matter as you are printing out instead of returning the value, but such solutions break when, say, you want to use the function more than once.